# Rivet pattern management in Fusion 360

Tags: aluminum, rivets, cad

As a follow up to [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7901/aluminum-for-an-ejection-seat-replica), I have a question about rivet hole management in Autodesk Fusion 360.

I've got two pieces, a flat sheet of aluminum and an inverted hat channel that I want to rivet together. The easy (and naive) way would be simply to specify a bunch of rivet holes in each piece while being careful to match the holes sizes and distances from each other.  And that works until I need/want to make changes to the rivet hole sizes or layout, then I have to go remember to change them on both pieces.

I am skeptical of any practice that relies on me remembering to do something in lots of places. I'd much rather create a kind of master rivet hole pattern that each piece inherits from.  That way, I make one change to the master and it's automatically propagated to all the places I need it.

How do I link the rivet hole sizes and pattern together so if I change it one place, it changes it in the other?  I've seen "Project geometry" but can't seem to figure out how to make it do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [video](http://fusion360.autodesk.com/learning/learning.html?guid=GUID-77275F36-81D1-49DD-B83A-1036C958B538) on how to use a single sketch to make multiple bodies from a single sketch.  It appears to do what I want.

The video transcript reads:

> Now that you've seen how 2D sketches drive 3D features, I'll switch over to another design to show you how a single sketch can be used to create multiple 3D features using different profiles. The sketch shown here has a few circular profiles and a tab extending at the top, along with a line on the left that will be used to create a Revolve feature. This will be the first 3D feature I'll create from this sketch, so I'll go ahead and enable the command from the "Create" drop-down menu and I can begin selecting closed profiles within the sketch. I can select as many as I need until I get the correct collective profile. As a side note, it's typically easiest to select all of your profiles from the top of the screen down to the bottom. I'll quickly finish this 3D feature by selecting the axis of revolution as well as change a few parameters for the feature.

Comment: The link is broken.